# Binding datepicker for radio buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have three radio button

Today   1Sept   Others.

```
<span class="spacing_10">
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="">
    <label for="radio3">Today</label>
</span>
<span class="spacing_10">
    <input type="radio" id="radio4" name="radios" value="">
    <label for="radio4">1 Aug</label>
</span>
<span class="spacing_10">
    <input type="radio" id="CoverStartDateOther" name="radios" value="">
    <label for="CoverStartDateOther">Other</label>
</span>
```

My requirement is simple. When i click on Others option, i have  to display Datepicker.

I have tried following code, but its not worked for me...

```
$('#CoverStartDateOther').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 2,

    });
```

And second requirement is, On selecting the date from the datepicker, i have to hide "others" text and have to show the date.

Please help me with this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery UI datepicker can be assigned only to an input `text` not a radio.

Docs:

> The datepicker is tied to a standard form input field. Focus on the
>   input (click, or use the tab key) to open an interactive calendar in a
>   small overlay. Choose a date, click elsewhere on the page (blur the
>   input), or hit the Esc key to close. If a date is chosen, feedback is
>   shown as the input's value.

So you have to refactor you HTML and JS by adding an field (eventually hidden) or an inline datepicker.

In this code I added an additional hidden field and the code to update the text of the radio, the update code fires in the `onSelect` option of the datepicker.

Html:

```
<span class="spacing_10">
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="">
    <label for="radio3">Today</label>
</span>

<span class="spacing_10">
    <input type="radio" id="radio4" name="radios" value="">
    <label for="radio4">1 Aug</label>
</span>

<span class="spacing_10">
    <input type="text" id="CoverStartDateOtherPicker" />
    <input type="radio" id="CoverStartDateOther" name="radios" value="">
    <label for="CoverStartDateOther">Other</label>

</span>
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#CoverStartDateOtherPicker").datepicker({
        onSelect: function () {
            $("label[for='CoverStartDateOther']").text($(this).val());
        }
    });

    $("#CoverStartDateOther").click(function () {
        $("#CoverStartDateOtherPicker").datepicker("show");
    });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/mrPUw/

Answer (score 1):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/nqQ6H/

**JS:-**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#CoverStartDateOther').click(function () {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 2
        });

        $('#datepicker').focus();
    });

    $('#datepicker').change(function(){
        $(".spacing_10").last().text($(this).val());
    });


});
```

**HTML:-**

```
<span class="spacing_10">
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="">
    <label for="radio3">Today</label>
</span>

<span class="spacing_10">
    <input type="radio" id="radio4" name="radios" value="">
    <label for="radio4">1 Aug</label>
</span>

<span class="spacing_10">
    <input type="radio" id="CoverStartDateOther" name="radios" value="">
    <label for="CoverStartDateOther">Other</label>

</span>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Answer (score 0):

**in html**

```
<span class="spacing_10">
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radios" value="">
    <label for="radio3">Today</label>
</span>
<span class="spacing_10">
    <input type="radio" id="radio4" name="radios" value="">
    <label for="radio4">1 Aug</label>
</span>
<span class="spacing_10">
    <input type="radio" id="CoverStartDateOther" name="radios" value="">
    <label for="CoverStartDateOther">Other</label>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
</span>
```

**in JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#datepicker").datepicker();

$(":radio").click(function(){
if($(this).attr("id")=="CoverStartDateOther")
{
$("#datepicker").focus();
}

});
});
```

Comment: Can't we bind it to radio button directly

Comment: date-picker apply in input text or in div  see here http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default for input box http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline for div